# Unable to retrieve databag items for a encrypted data bag using chef attributes

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, cookbook

I am working on this recipe which assigns api key from an encrypted data bag item. To retrieve the data bag item I am using chef attributes in the query. This is what I am doing to assign the attributes

```
ruby_block "get_my_region" do
  block do
    node.set['aws']['account_number'] = `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|grep region|awk -F\\" '{print $4}'`.chop
    node.save
  end
  action :create
end

ruby_block "get_account" do
    block do
      node.set['aws']['region'] = `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep -oP '(?<="accountId" : ")[^"]*(?=")'`.chop
      node.save
    end
    action :create
end
```

Once the attributes get assigned I am calling a template to using the assigned attribute to the config file

```
template '/etc/default/polymur-proxy' do
  source 'polymur-proxy.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'service[polymur-proxy]', :delayed
  variables(
  api_key: (api_keys["#{node['aws']['region']}"]["#{node['aws']['account_number']}"]["key"]).to_s,
  )
end
```

The problem is the while debugging I can see the attribute got assigned the correct values however while using them in the query they return empty. If any one has any suggestion for this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing [Chef's two pass](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/) execution model, template variables are evaluated before ruby_block resources calls. You can wrap `api_keys` with lazy block.

However, there is no need to manually call curl on AWS metadata endpoint. Chef's ohai ec2 plugin is extracting them anyway - `node["ec2"]["account_id"]` and `node["ec2"]["availability_zone"]` (just drop az id here wit `tr` or `gsub`). You can pass this right to the template or even use `node` directly in your template.